# Launch app from URL issue

Tags: ios, xcode, url-scheme

I'm trying to launch my app using URL from Safari.

```
-(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation {
    NSLog(@"Launched with URL");
    return YES;
}

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    NSLog(@"Launched normally");
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    return YES;
}
```

(Also tried `-(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application handleOpenURL:(NSURL *)url`
)
If the app is in the background (i.e, if I double click the home button, it's there) the app launches correctly and console shows `Launched with URL`.
However, if I close it completely, meaning, double clicking home button, holding the app and clicking the minus sign, when trying to launch it again via Safari, it just shows a black screen and logs nothing to console.

This happens both on the device and simulator (5.1 both)
Is there another delegate which should be called when the app is completely closed?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you add the URL scheme to your info.plist?

Comment: Yes. If the app is in background and i log the text being sent using the URL scheme, it shows fine. only if it's closed it just stuck on a black window

Comment: You usually have also [self.window makeKeyAndVisible]; in both methods.

Comment: I think it was totally my fault.. When I disconnected the device from the computer, it started working. I believe it was happening because of killing the app disabled the debugging (SIGKILL) and when relaunching it, it failed.
When not connected, it works.

Answer (score 1):

If your application is opening from Safari, this means you have implemented the URL schema correctly. 
Handle the Opened URl in these application delegate events

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
}
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application handleOpenURL:(NSURL *)url 
{
}
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:
                                                        (NSString *)sourceApplication
                                                        annotation:(id)annotation
{
}
```

Just Make sure you have properly encoded your URL it might be the case that your URL is breaking.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, That's what I did. But still, if the app is completely closed, when launched, it stucks on a black screen. if it was in the background, it works.

Comment: can you post the url you are using to open your application.